# macOS Disk Utility shows too many disks

Tags: mac, storage, boot-camp

I installed Windows 10 on my MacBook using Bootcamp. While I was doing it I noticed that Disk Utility showed me that I had 4 disks on my computer. I bought this Mac from a person a little while ago, so I have no idea why there are so many disks on it.

There is one 256GB SSD installed on my MacBook.

Can anyone please explain? Which of those disks can I delete to keep everything nice and tidy?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many individual HDDs or SSDs are actually installed in the system?  How many partitions per disk are there supposed to be?  Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question

Comment: I'd say "If it ain't broke, don't fix it". Modifying partitions has the inherent risk of data loss and system corruption.

Comment: @Ramhound there is only one ssd installed on my mac